# How to draw a route from current location to a markerpoint on Android Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm new creating apps and I want to show a drawn route in a Google Map starting from the current location. I've just found how to get the current location, but now I'm stuck in the second part, which is drawing the route from the current location to another marker point.

Here is my code:

```
`public class Trazo_Rutas extends FragmentActivity implements 
                         OnMapReadyCallback,
                         GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                         GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                         LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
Location lastLocation;
Marker userLocation;
private static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trazo__rutas);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkUserLocationPermission();
    }

    //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
    if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
    }

    //AutoComplete search bar
    placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
    placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    0).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    //get latlong for corners for specified place
    LatLng corner1 = new LatLng(25.64379, -103.60966);
    LatLng corner2 = new LatLng(25.64317, -103.20935);
    LatLng corner3 = new LatLng(25.43872, -103.61104);
    LatLng corner4 = new LatLng(25.43748, -103.20866);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    builder.include(corner1);
    builder.include(corner2);
    builder.include(corner3);
    builder.include(corner4);

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    //add them to builder
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    // 20% padding
    int padding = (int) (width * 0.20);

    //set latlng bounds
    mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds);

    //move camera to fill the bound to screen
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding));

    //set zoom to level to current so that you won't be able to zoom out viz. move outside bounds
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}

public boolean checkUserLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, Request_User_Location_Code);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, Request_User_Location_Code);
        }

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_User_Location_Code:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (googleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }

                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se requieren Permisos de Google", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

            return;
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;

    if (userLocation != null) {
        userLocation.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.draggable(true);
    markerOptions.title("Tu ubicación");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

    userLocation = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));

    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

}`
```

My concern is that I don't know how to implement the other marker and draw the route.
Thank you.